# Dúvida com JMS no Java e implementação

Tags: java-ee, jboss, wildfly

Estou precisando fazer um publisher/subscriber simples em JMS, mas estou cheio de dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento já que não tenho muita noção da arquitetura e nem da implementação no Java.

Pelo que entendi o funcionamento pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

1. Configuro o servidor JBoss para iniciar o JMS. (Não preciso de nenhuma aplicação aqui).
2. Crio um cliente publisher e um cliente subscriber que se conectam nesse servidor JBoss...
   Vi uma referência de implementação para clientes publisher/subscriber aqui: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/JMS_Examples-A_Pub_Sub_Example.html e nesse caso ambos podem ser aplicações java SE, desktop mesmo, correto?

Bom, minha dúvida é a seguinte:

1. Isso que estou pensando está correto?
2. Como configuro o JMS no wildfly (novo JBoss)? apenas no arquivo standalone.xml? como seria?

Comment: A JMS 2.0 (jsr 914 e 343) é uma especificação do Java EE 7, que suporta tanto filas quanto tópicos. Nesse caso a implementação padrão é o HornetQ, projeto da própria JBoss. Sim, é possivel criar produtores remotos (não tenho pleno conhecimento para afirmar o contrário), mas não obrigatoriamente Desktop. Uma boa referência inicial seria o tutorial do Java EE (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partmessaging.htm#GFIRP3). A configuração no wildfly é feita tanto no standalone quanto por código, uma boa referencia são: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Messaging+configuration.

Comment: Ah, lembrando que apenas o Wildfly Full Profile permite o uso da JMS.